# Unable to call etsy API using google apps script

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script

Basically i want to get the all sold orders details from etsy.
I have found the ajax api call which etsy make to fetch all order details in browser's network tool, and if i simply call this url in new tab from browser im getting a proper well defined json response.

See the below image:

[image: You can see the response]

Now i want to achieve this using google apps script. I searched and did many trial & error but couldn't able to get through it. Sometimes i got "Not logged in" and sometime "Resource not found".

I am sharing the my hard raw code which i had changed more than 30 times, please help me out with this.

```
  function webScrape(){
    var url = "https://www.etsy.com/api/v3/ajax/shop/5678443/mission-control/orders"

    var options = {
    "headers": {
      "Origin": "https//www.etsy.com",
    },
    "payload":{
      "username":"xxxxxxx",
      "password":"xxxxxxx"
    },
   "method"  : "GET",   
   "followRedirects" : true,
   "muteHttpExceptions": true
  }
  var login=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(login);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Etsy API Introduction](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/register) and then the [Etsy API Basics](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/api_basics). You need to setup an Etsy App then use the authorization code to make requests.

It looks like [this findAllShopReceipts call](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/receipt#method_findallshopreceipts) will give you order information for a shop.

```
https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/:shopid/receipts/
```

But it also looks like you need to setup and use OAuth *v1* (not v2) on [Etsy](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/oauth) and then on [Apps Script](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1) to use this call.